# Passing variable from servlet to JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jstl, el

I've seen other questions similar to this asked but none of them have helped me solve my problem. Basically, I'm trying to pass a variable from a servlet to a JSP.

The servlet code.

```
package com.servlets;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.dao.DataGetter;

@WebServlet("/DataGetterServlet")
public class DataGetterServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    ArrayList<String[]> data;
    private DataGetter dg;

    public void init() throws ServletException {
        try {
            dg = new DataGetter();
            data = dg.getData();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new ServletException("An exception occurred in DataGetterServlet: " 
                + e.getClass().getName());
        }
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
        throws ServletException, IOException {

        request.setAttribute("data", data);
        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");
        rd.forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

My JSP code

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" 
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Data extractor</title>
</head>

<body>
    Data table:

    <table boder="1">
        <c:forEach var="item" items="${data}" >
            <tr>
                <c:forEach var="column" items="${item}">
                    <td>${column}</td> 
                </c:forEach>
            </tr> 
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

I have done some tests with the forEach tag and JSTL is setup properly. I think the variable "data" is not reaching the JSP. Any idea why?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** For clarification porpuses. I have tried

```
<c:forEach var="i" begin="1" end="5">
   Item <c:out value="${i}"/><p>
</c:forEach>
```

And that works, but

```
<c:forEach var="item" items="${data}">
   It worked!<p>
</c:forEach>
```

doesn't work. This is what has led me to believe that that variable data is not reaching the JSP for some reason.

**EDIT 2:** To run it, I configured a Tomcat server on Eclipse. I right click on the servlet and choose Run As -> Run on Server. The server restarts and I launch `http://localhost:8080/DataExtractor/` from my browser. Here's the resulting html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Data extractor</title>
</head>

<body>
Data table:
    <table border="1">

    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT 3:** This might be the key of why this is happening. When I go to `http://localhost:8080/DataExtractor/` (index.jsp), I get the html posted in **Edit 2**, but if I go to `http://localhost:8080/DataExtractor/DataGetterServlet` then I do get the right page! Any idea why?

Comment: Are you sure that the "data" array variable in the servlet actually has values when you are adding it to the request?

Comment: Yes, I've checked and I can say for sure that the ArrayList is properly populated.

Comment: Are you sure your arrayList is not empty list? If it is empty, then the loop won't iterate

Comment: 100% sure. I threw Exceptions in my servlet init() method with values such as `data.get(0)[0]` to check and the ArrayList and internal arrays are populated correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might be a typo, `$(item)` should be `${item}` in the following -

```
<c:forEach var="column" items="$(item)" >
```

**Update**

`http://localhost:8080/DataExtractor/` that doesn't map to the servlet, while `http://localhost:8080/DataExtractor/DataGetterServlet` does. If the servlet isn't invoked then it's obvious that `data` is not going to be the request. In other words, the first url is not invoking the servlet, but directly talking you to the page. (You probably have as welcome-page in web.xml)

Comment: Can update your question with the full definition of the servlet and also can you show how are you firing the request?

Comment: Have you also been checking the tomcat's log file?

Comment: @fpele: Updated it with the comment. Took a while but you nailed it anyway. Great effort and good job. +1.

Answer (score 2):

In the jsp, you need to include this in the header:

```
<jsp:useBean id="data" class="java.util.ArrayList" scope="request"/>
```

Comment: That has to work. Just, make sure to have ArrayList<String> instead of ArrayList<String[]>.

Comment: This is not required - [*In any case, if you're using a servlet, you should not be using <jsp:useBean> ...*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14588073/738746)

Comment: Exactly @BheshGurung, I'm following a different MVC model, where my servlet is instantiating a DAO and then dispatching the data to the JSP. As I understand, if you are using beans, you can remove the servlet altogether. Am I right?

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem was because of typo only.

```
<c:forEach var = "column" items = "${data}">
```

and

```
<c:forEach var = "column" items = "${requestScope.data}">
```

worked well for me because requestScope holds the map of request objects.

Comment: Thank you for noticing. I did have that typo in my code, but that's not the real problem. Please see the edit I made for clarification.